# can I use multiple selectors for opendkim?

Tags: postfix, email-server, opendkim

I have 4 domains hosted on a single server. Should I use 4 separate dkim keys or one for all of them?

Also as far as selectors go do I need to use the one specified in opendkim.conf or can/should I create a new one per each domain with new key?

Answer (score 6):

> I have 4 domains hosted on a single server. Should I use 4 separate DKIM keys or one for all of them?

Technically you can use the same key-pair to generate DKIM signatures for all the domains you host on the same mail server. That may be preferable when you host (many) different domains.

- Publish DKIM record once in the DNS zone for your main domain i.e.
  `dkim.example.net.      86400   IN  TXT "k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSq...DAQAB\;"`
- For all your domains you'll need to use the same `selector-name` and set up domainkey DNS records such as:
  `selector-name._domainkey   IN CNAME dkim.example.net.`

Then set up 
`/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```
KeyTable        /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
```

In `/etc/opendkim/KeyTable`:

```
selector-name  example.com:selector-name:/etc/opendkim/selector-name.key
```

And in `/etc/opendkim/SigningTable` map every domain to that single key:

```
* selector-name
```

---

For a limited number of domains I usually generate unique key pairs (`opendkim-genkey --domain=example.com --selector=20180717 --verbose`) for each domain and maintain the opendkim `KeyTable` and `SigningTable` mappings.

In `/etc/opendkim/KeyTable`:

```
selector-name._domainkey.example.com  example.com:selector-name:/etc/opendkim/selector-name._domainkey.example.com.key
selector-name._domainkey.example.org  example.org:selector-name:/etc/opendkim/selector-name._domainkey.example.org.key
```

And in `/etc/opendkim/SigningTable` map every domain to its own key:

```
example.com selector-name._domainkey.example.com
example.org selector-name._domainkey.example.org
```

Comment: When generating new unique keys for domains do I need to use selector from openkim.conf? or can I have different selectors as long I specify them in signing and key tables?

Im confused on why opendkim.conf has selector option in thereif they get specified in key and signing table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use different keys for different domains.
You don't need to specify them with same `Selector`, as when `KeyTable` is used, `Selector` configuration parameter is not used.